# Rotate value of Element in InDesign

Tags: javascript, indesign-server

I wonder if it is possible to get the rotate value from an ImageElement in an InDesign element with a custom script?
I am new to InDesign server scripting, but have start learning if this is possible.

Comment: This is an interesting question to be asked on Stackoverflow. But it is development related. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps... This gets all images rotation Angle.

```
var pageItems = app.activeWindow.activePage.allPageItems;
var itemsCount = pageItems.length;

for(var i=0; i<itemsCount; i++)
{
  if(pageItems[i] instanceof Image)
  {
    var graphic = pageItems[i];

    var rotation = graphic.rotationAngle;

  }

}
```